# How to allow communicatation between two pods from two different clusters with the same Istio control plane (GCP managed) and within same network

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-gateway

I have two workloads deployed in cluster1 and cluster2 within same VPC and within same namespace. I need to allow communication between them using services, I am creating same namespaces in two clusters and two deployments with services

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  labels:
    istio.io/rev: asm-managed-stable
  name: test1
  annotations:
    mesh.cloud.google.com/proxy: '{"managed": true}'
```

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-v1
  namespace: test1
spec:
  selector:
    app: test-v1
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  type: ClusterIP
```

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-v2
  namespace: test1
spec:
  selector:
    app: test-v2
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  type: ClusterIP
```

And I am trying to access service test-v2 from the first deployment by the url
*http://test-v2.test1.svc.cluster.local:8080* and there is no access.

UPD:
I have found that problem is in DNS resolving, it is not possible to multicluster resolve service DNS without dns proxy. So the question is it possible to access services through dns names without istio dns proxy?

Comment: You have a typo in your URL - it should be "test1" for the namespace (E.g. `test-v2.test1.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: Thanks, changed, this is just post typo

Comment: ah. I am assuming you followed the walkthroughs here: https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/ and the troubleshooting section (https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/diagnostic-tools/multicluster/)?

Comment: Mister DISCO, try to troubleshoot connectivity with internal ips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Communication possible within internal service IPs, to allow communication using DNS service names add [dns proxy](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/dns-proxy/) annotations to pod

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sleep
spec:
...
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        proxy.istio.io/config: |
          proxyMetadata:
            ISTIO_META_DNS_CAPTURE: "true"
            ISTIO_META_DNS_AUTO_ALLOCATE: "true"
```